# how to compare 2 checkbox'es values

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Here http://jsfiddle.net/SW5NH/5/ I created some automatically generated table (DOM + JavaScript).

I want to compare whether checkbox's Input1[z] value (true/false) is equal to Input2's[z] value.
If they are not equal value[z] should change.

Tried in several ways (below the table are some test results), but can not achieve it.
I would appreciate for any help/comments.

```
function valCheck() {
    for (var y2 = 0; y2 < empl.length; y2++) {
        var Id1 = 'Option1'+y2+'';
        var Id2 = 'Option2'+y2;
        var input1 = document.getElementById(Id1).checked;
        var input2 = document.getElementById(Id2).checked;
        var value = 'Value'+y2+''; 
        var valEntry = document.getElementById(value);
        var debt = (input1==input2) ? 'no debt' : 'debt';
        document.getElementById('tabinfo').innerHTML = Id1+input1+ ' ' +Id2+input2+ ' ' +(input1&&input2)+value+valEntry+ ' ' + debt;
        document.getElementById(value).createTextNode(debt);
        }
    }
```

don't work

UPDATE: Solved. Solution in my last post.

Comment: It looks like you're only executing `valCheck` when the window first loads. SHouldn't you be checking it every time something gets checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here what you need, [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rQsSw/)

```
function checkValue() {
        var a = document.getElementById('a');
        var b = document.getElementById('b');
        if (a.checked != b.checked) {
            document.getElementById('lab').innerHTML="Not equal";
        }

        else
            document.getElementById('lab').innerHTML = "equal";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comparsion is right but you should be using '**change**' eventListener like this

```
document.addEventListener('change', valCheck, false);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SW5NH/7/) and share your suggestion.

Also use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: Thank you for a tip. Also it seems, that it works on Chrome, not in IE.

Comment: @user2587277 Do you have `console.log` in your `js`.  If so remove it.   IE does not allow `console.log`.

Comment: thank you very much. Now it shows values in 'tabinfo'. But only of row 1 and not in table's 5 col. Maybe I should add eventlisteners to every input and compare in other way (without loop)?

Comment: Also , value of 5th col - valEntry  is 'null'.

Comment: @user2587277 Yes, there is no element with such id.  That is the reason for null.

Comment: I've found that my table creating algoritm causes this problem with wrong ID's. I will try to correct it http://jsfiddle.net/SW5NH/15/ here is the last version atm.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all.

My table works now and it rocks already :) It is still in progress, but there are waiting only some cosmetic amendments.

Here is the actual JSFidle http://jsfiddle.net/5tcPz/1
You are welcome to use it if you find it usefull.

My mistake was - document.createTextNode element can't have an ID, so the value of Element value[z] was null.

I solved it in such way:

```
var fifthCell = document.createElement('DIV');
    fifthCell.id = "Value" + y + '';
    fifthCellText = document.createTextNode('no debt');
    fifthCell.appendChild(fifthCellText);
```

UPDATE.
http://jsfiddle.net/5dmrW finished table!!! This was my first JavaScript project after codeacademy and a lot of JS online tutorials :) It's a very simple, but I'm proud of it. Regards